# React Native typescript Unexpected token in catch clause

Tags: typescript, react-native, metro-bundler

I have a fully configured react native typescript project and everything is working as expected, but I have a strange issue:

I all of my catch blocks, since I have strict mode enabled, I have typescript errors like this one [image]

So the first obvious thing to do was to add `any` type to the error object

[image]

Ok, error gone. But at this point the problem in in RN bundler:

[image]

I am pretty sure that it's caused by some sort of wrong typescript configuration, but I really don't have any idea of what to check, any help?

Comment: It's possible that you forgot to compile your `ts` file. Like you're running command `node file.ts`. Is it the reason or not?

Comment: In React Native the transpiling process is done by metro bundler, so the answer is no, it's not that the reason

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

Just updated some babel related packages and it works now

```
@babel/core: ^7.6.2t --> ^7.12.9
@babel/runtime: ^7.6.2 --> ^7.12.5
metro-react-native-babel-preset: ^0.58.0 --> ^0.66.0
```